# NavigationBar hiding cells in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to create a CollectionView with cells. However, it seems to keep hiding the top of the first cells. Of course, I can set the top insets, however, isn't there another way to do it, or what am I doing wrong?

I've created a UICollectionViewController and set the following.

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject!) -> PFCollectionViewCell? {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ItemCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? BrowseCell

    cell?.titleLabel.text = object["title"] as! NSString as String
   // cell?.myImageView.file = (object["images"] as [PFFile]).first
    cell?.clipsToBounds = true

    return cell
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 10
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10)
}
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width/2-15, 100)
}
```

an image[image]

Comment: Are you creating the CollectionView in code of from the storyboard?

Comment: i've created a collectionviewcontroller in storyboard

Comment: You can adjust the `CollectionView` in the Storyboard so the top is directly aligned with the bottom of the navigation bar and then set the top constraint for the `CollectionView`